# Eslint no-extraneous-dependencies error with npm workspaces

Tags: eslint, monorepo, npm-workspaces

I've set up my monorepo using NPM workspaces with the following high-level structure:

```
root
  common      // Shared package, named @company/common
    src
      ...
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
  web         // ReactJS package, named @company/web
    config
      ...
    public
      ...
    src
      ...
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
  mobile      // React Native package, named @company/mobile
    ...
    package.json
    tsconfig.json
  .eslintrc.json
  .prettierrc
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  tsconfig.base.json
```

All my packages are meant to be private and have been marked as such in their respective `package.json` files.

I've successfully managed to set everything up such that I can write code like this in the web and mobile workspaces:

`import { ITestInterface } from '@company/common';`

With my current setup, I get an eslint warning in my IDE (VS Code) whenever I open any file that imports anything from `@company/common`:
`'@company/common' should be listed in the project's dependencies. Run 'npm i -S @company/common' to add it`

I'd rather not disable this warning entirely if at all possible. Is there a way to configure eslint to have it understand monorepos so that it does not give me a warning when I try to import something from a package (workspace) within my monorepo?

Comment: Did you find a nice solution? We are having the same issues with a `turbo` / `nuxt` /`monorepo`.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem in our monorepo using a similar setup (one eslintrc file in root) which took quite some time to find a suitable solution for.

In our eslintrc, we had this:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    settings: {
                'import/resolver': {
                    typescript: {
                        extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
                        project: ['**/tsconfig.json'],
                    },
                },
    ...
}
```

Which worked pretty well, except for tons of *no-extraneous-dependencies*. In the end, we had to create an additional eslintrc file for each project, like this:

```
   root
       team-one
          team-one-frontend
                .eslintrc.js
                tsconfig.json
          team-one-frontend2
                .eslintrc.js
                tsconfig.json
       team-two
          team-two-frontend
                .eslintrc.js
                tsconfig.json
          team-two-frontend2
                .eslintrc.js
                tsconfig.json
   .eslintrc.js
   .eslintignore
```

Each project-specific eslintrc file would only be overriding where to look for tsconfig files, while using all the rules and other config from root. So for example, `.eslintrc.js.` in  team-one-frontend would contain this:

```
module.exports = {
    settings: {
        'import/resolver': {
            typescript: {
                project: ['team-one/team-one-frontend'],
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Same content with the three other paths in the three other projects.

Comment: Not the solution I'd like to use but the one I'm using at the moment, ideally I'd like to have only one .eslintrc and not one for each workspace

Answer (score 0):

Maybe moving the `.eslintrc.json` to each individual package? Have you tried to run `npm install` again in the root?

My setup is like this and I don't have this issue.

```
root
  back-end
    src/
    .eslintrc.js
    tsconfig.json
    tsconfig.ref.json
    package.json
  front-end
    src/
    .eslintrc.js
    tsconfig.json
    tsconfig.ref.json
    package.json
  shared
    // some .ts files
    package.json
package.json
tsconfig.json
```

If you wonder about tsconfig.ref.json, here is an example how to set it up: https://2ality.com/2021/07/simple-monorepos.html